# Unable to save contents once a <img> tag is added

Tags: nodes

I try to add new contents and added a content with an image tag in it. It could be as simple as:

```
<img>
Hello
```

When I try to save, the page merely reloads and nothing is saved, no error messages and I am still at the same page.

Adding new contents without the  tag saves with no problem. Adding new contents with just the  tag also saves with no problem.

Only contents with an  tag AND some other contents not save.

This problem came up suddenly. I have not updated Drupal nor any of my modules. And I have confirmed that I have allowed  as a tag in my text format.

Would anyone know what problem this may be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem. It has absolutely nothing to do with images. The web hosting company configured modsecurity and it broke the way Drupal does POST in some instances.